# Animation in a table view cell

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm not sure if it is possible to achieve, but my costumer wants that when user taps a table view cell, an animation of a UIView sliding from left to right is committed, leaving the content under the UIView visible.

My concern is about how to trigger gesture recognizer added to the upper UIVIew for the animation and do not enter in conflict with didSelectRowatIndex: table view delegate method.

Is it possible to achieve?

Mant thanks!

Comment: So you need to do this if there's a TAP or a SLIDE gesture on the table view cel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search on CocoaControls.com for this kind of control, there are plenty of open-source code that does this already.

After searching for "cell" on www.cocoacontrols.com I can already find the following ones:

- [JBSlidingTableviewCell](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jbslidingtableviewcell)
- [LRSlidingTableviewCell](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/lrslidingtableviewcell)
- [ZKRevealingTablecellView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/zkrevealingtablecellview)
- [DMSlidingCell](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/dmslidingcell)
- [TISwipeableTableview](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/tiswipeabletableview)

And there is probably more.